# PHP Dom Extension - Can I disable it

Tags: php

Can I disable the PHP Dom Extension temporarily (for debug reasons), without having to reinstall / recompile PHP?

I want to install the module and I'm looking for a way to temporarily turn it off, so that I can turn it back on at another time.

Comment: `--enable-dom=false` during install might be what you're looking for

Comment: ok, but I mean temporarily, after installation

Comment: As @Martijn suggests, the only way to truly "disable" the extension is at compile time (also `--disable-dom` - http://php.net/manual/en/dom.installation.php). If this is for "debugging", can you not simulate (unit test) this?

Answer (score 1):

Your extension has [no runtime configuration options](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.configuration.php).   If it cannot be controlled from php.ini, then your only option would be to un-install it and re-install it later.